# Hear the audio of bluetooth and logitech mic from the USB soundcard

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I have Syba USB audio souncard (That contain two pins one for mic and one for speaker). I have load the module-loopback using the following command:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-mono sink=alsa_output.usb-0d8c_C-Media_USB_Audio_Device-00-Device.analog-stereo latency_msec=1 source_dont_move=yes
```

Now the I am able to hear the audio from the USB soundcard speaker that I speak from the same USB soundcard mic.

I have also another two audio devices like logitech mic and bluetooth device that are already connected to the system.

I want the hear audio of both logitech mic and bluetooth devices also in the USB soundcard speaker.

Please let us know your thought?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem. To hear the live audio of logitech mic and bluetooth device from USB soundcard speaker, we have to load the module-loopback related to the logitech mic and bluetooth device. So we can hear the live audio of logitech mic and bluetooth from USB souncard speaker.

Following are command that I have used to load all the module-loopback.

To load logitech mic loopback-module:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_D81A0330-00-U0x46d0x823_1.analog-stereo sink=alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_D81A0330-00-U0x46d0x823_1.analog-stereo latency_msec=1 source_dont_move=yes
```

Now I am able to hear the live audio form the devices that I loaded the module.